# Prevent users to delete comments after certain amount of time if there is a reply

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Anyone can delete his/her own comment anytime. This feature sometimes is not helpful, as some comments have reply backs and which makes sense only knowing the context. I don't know why some users delete their comments ?

e.g. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/273251/1135954 the comments makes no sense because OP deleted his previous comment.

This make the post look like a broken link, and SO is a place with good info and content. So it's looks contrary.

I think comment deletion should be prohibited after a span of some reasonable time (1hr? 1 day?).

Of course, comments that are harmful in nature, that are not constructive can always be flagged and moderator can delete those?

What are your concerns over this?

Comment: Many times comments also have useful info just as the post/answer

Comment: If I made a statement that was wrong in a comment, and someone corrected me, I think it is *most* helpful that I delete the comment containing wrong information. That way, people don't get confused about what's right, and they don't have to waste time reading wrong stuff that they will immediately have to try to forget. This isn't a chat page; you shouldn't need the full context of a conversion to benefit from a useful comment.

Comment: More responsibility is being put on the answers to update the post with proper info from the deleted comments. It should be OPs job.

Comment: Comments are temporary 'post-it' notes. They are not permanent.  
Do not expect them to be permanent.  
Comments are also not for back and forth discussion. If you want a more permanent way to store back and forth discussion, use chat.

Answer (score 10):

Comments are temporal.  If the comment no longer makes sense in context, then it should be flagged for removal; ideally as "obsolete".  The only thing we should strive to preserve are the answers.

Answer (score 9):

This is unnecessary because comments aren't *supposed* to live forever or form part of a permanent dialog. We *want* users to clean up their own comments if they are no longer helpful (and, hopefully, flag the rest of the conversation as obsolete when appropriate).

The posts, not the comments, should contain all essential information about a problem or its solution. Comments only serve to help the posts get to that point. Some key points:

- Comments are *temporary*. From [the help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

  > **Comments are temporary** "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.
- Comments are *"second-class citizens."* (BTW, anyone have the canonical source for this term as applied to comments?)
- Comments *can be flagged as obsolete*.

In fact, that last point is exactly how to handle the kind of situation you describe. If you see a comment that only makes sense with context that no longer exists, flag the comment.